# Contour plot in one graph

Tags: r, plot

```
mu1 <- c(0,0)
mu2<-c(2*sqrt(2),2*sqrt(2))
sigma1 <- matrix(c(2,0,.0,2), nrow=2)
sigma2<-matrix(c(2, 1.2, 1.2, 2),ncol = 2)
data.grid <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-6, 10, length.out=100), s.2 = seq(-6, 10, length.out=100))
q.samp1 <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = mu1, sigma = sigma1))
q.samp2 <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid1, mean = mu2, sigma =sigma2))
```

my code for this plot is following:

```
ggplot(q.samp1, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob)) +
  stat_contour(color = 'red',bins = 12 ) + 
  stat_contour(data = q.samp2, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob), color = 'green',bins = 12,binwidth = 1)+geom_point(aes(x = 0, y =0))+
  geom_point(aes(x=2*sqrt(2),y=2*sqrt(2)))+xlab("Random slop")+ylab("Random intercept")
```

I want to contour a plot of the above data like the following image in R, please help me
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with ggplot with the stats_contour() command, but I couldn't draw the line between the two centers of the circle, and my output has more than one line. I will share my code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code - could you add it to your original question as an additional code block please?  It makes it easier for people to copy/work with.

Comment: If you only want one ring, set `bins = 2` instead of 12.  Also your provided code does not work - you do not define `data.grid1`.

Comment: edited. please check my code. and note that i want 12th line. if write bins=2 the circle is small.